# Image Processing in QT using openCV

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, image-processing

i am using opencv2.3.1 in QT for detecting circle.

my Open CV Directory is  D:\OpenCV

Here my Code:

Project File:

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = ImgProcessing
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui


INCLUDEPATH +=D:\\opencv\\build\\include

LIBS += -LD:\\opencv\\build\\x86\\vc10\\lib \
    -lopencv_calib3d231d \
    -lopencv_contrib231d \
    -lopencv_core231d \
    -lopencv_features2d231d \
    -lopencv_flann231d \
    -lopencv_gpu231d \
    -lopencv_haartraining_engined \
    -lopencv_highgui231d \
    -lopencv_imgproc231d \
    -lopencv_legacy231d \
    -lopencv_ml231d \
    -lopencv_objdetect231d \
    -lopencv_ts231d \
    -lopencv_video231d
```

and in the main window i put QPushButton on the Click event i am try to do the image processing

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    cv::Mat matOrg=cv::imread("D:\\temp\\Test_mar26-5-1.bmp");
    cv::Mat matProcessed;

    std::vector<cv::Vec3f> vecCircles;
    std::vector<cv::Vec3f>::iterator itrCircles;

    cv::inRange(matOrg,cv::Scalar(0,0,175),cv::Scalar(100,100,256),matProcessed);
    cv::GaussianBlur(matProcessed,matProcessed,cv::Size(9,9),1.5);
    cv::HoughCircles(matProcessed,vecCircles,CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT,2,matProcessed.rows/4,100,50,10,400);

    for(itrCircles =vecCircles.begin();itrCircles !=vecCircles.end();itrCircles++)
    {
        ui->plainTextEdit->appendPlainText(QString("X: ")+ QString::number((*itrCircles)[0]));
        ui->plainTextEdit->appendPlainText(QString("Y: ")+ QString::number((*itrCircles)[1]));
        ui->plainTextEdit->appendPlainText(QString("Radius: ")+ QString::number((*itrCircles)[2]));
    }
}
```

the project building with out any issue. but the problem is when i try to run the program i am getting following error

> Starting
>
> D:\ImgProcessing-build-Desktop_Qt_5_0_0_MSVC2010_32bit_SDK\debug\ImgProcessing.exe...
>
> The program has unexpectedly finished.
>
> D:\ImgProcessing-build-Desktop_Qt_5_0_0_MSVC2010_32bit_SDK\debug\ImgProcessing.exe
>     exited with code -1073741515

I am not getting why it's not running? and if try to comment the whole block it's running.(no image processing code). when i enable the cv::mat variable that time onwards i am getting the runtime error.

please help me to fix the issue.
the image i am trying to process is below
[image]

Comment: What does your debugger say?

Comment: when i click build. it's building without any issue. when i click run i am getting the error "The program has unexpectedly finished."

Comment: And none of those are your debugger.  Hit the play button with the beetle on it, and Qt Creator will launch your app through the debugger and open the debug perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Only comment the block:

```
for(itrCircles =vecCircles.begin();itrCircles !=vecCircles.end();itrCircles++)
{
    ui->plainTextEdit->appendPlainText(QString("X: ")+ QString::number((*itrCircles)[0]));
    ui->plainTextEdit->appendPlainText(QString("Y: ")+ QString::number((*itrCircles)[1]));
    ui->plainTextEdit->appendPlainText(QString("Radius: ")+ QString::number((*itrCircles)[2]));
}
```

there may be a problem with vecCircles. But as a valid approach you should debug step by step

Comment: i commented all and i enabled only cv::mat matOrg; i started getting the error

Comment: D:\\temp\\Test_mar26-5-1.bmp file exists really?

Answer (score 0):

The code worked fine for me, no error at all. But `vecCircles.size()` shows zero here. Please build on debug mode and find breakpoints (keep pressing F10).

Answer (score 0):

You may try to but OpenCV .dll files according to the .lib files you added, for example put *opencv_world320.dll* into the same directory of you .exe file.

Note that .dll files differ in debug mode and release mode, for example, *opencv_world320.dll* is for release mode, but *opencv_world320**d**.dll* is for debug mode.

.dll files can be found under opencv/build/bin directory.